# Checkbox is not working when selected by itself

Tags: jquery

I have a table and each row has a checkbox.

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
       content
    </td>
</tr>
... more rows
</table>
```

I would like to check/uncheck the checkbox and change the class when I click on a row. This works great, however, when I click on a checkbox itself, nothing happens. literally, not even able to check/uncheck.

```
$(document).on("click", "#myTable tr", function() {
        var ths = $(this),
            chk = ths.find(".checkbox");

        if (chk.is(":checked")) {
            ths.removeClass("success");
            chk.prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            ths.addClass("success");
            chk.prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
```

Not really sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Why are you manually altering the checked state with `chk.prop("checked"`?

Comment: It's because when you click the actual checkbox, the click event bubbles up to the table row so you are effectively running this code twice, so the box checks and then immediately unchecks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event, on checkbox click, bubbles up to the TR and switches twice - because TR click does that.

#### Solution:

since [stopping Event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) is in general a sloppy idea<sup>1</sup>, you could instead  **detect who was the first element to receive the event ([`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target))**  - and act accordingly:

```js
$("#myTable").on("click", "tr", function(evt) {

  var $tr = $(this),
      chk = $tr.find(".checkbox")[0]; // ! Not a jQuery Object, but a JS Element
  
  // If checkbox was NOT the direct Event.target
  if (chk !== evt.target) {
    chk.checked = !chk.checked; // toggle artificially the checkbox state
  }
  
  // Do the following on whoever was the Event.target
  $tr.toggleClass("success", chk.checked);

});
```

```css
.success { background: #0bf; }
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that if `#myTable` ***is* the static [delegateTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) handler** for the [event attaching to current or future](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) `tr` elements, than use  `$("#myTable")` instead of `$(document)` as your static selector.

---

<sup>1</sup> To argument why [using `Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is **preferred** over `Event.stopPropagation()`:
take i.e: an element like `<body>`, waiting hungrily for an **event** to trigger a notification, or close an opened modal, but never registering it - resulting in a broken User Interface.